# What would happen if I plug in two USB-C power supplies into the same Mac? Would it charge faster?

Tags: usb, power

I have a bunch of USB-C power supplies (some at different wattages).

Would my Mac charge faster (or blow up) if I plug two power supplies into the same computer (different USB-C slots)

Answer (score 3):

**No**.

Your MacBook will charge from the one which provides higher power. Quoting from the Apple support document, [Connect with Thunderbolt 3 on your new MacBook Pro](https://web.archive.org/web/20180323044319/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207256):

> Notes on charging your MacBook Pro:
>
> - Your MacBook Pro draws power from only one power supply, even if more than one is attached—so using multiple power supplies won't speed up charging.
> - If you connect multiple power supplies to your MacBook Pro, the one that provides the most power will be used, regardless of the order in which you connected them.
> - You shouldn't connect any power supply that exceeds 100W, as it might damage your MacBook Pro. Also, using a power supply that doesn't provide sufficient power can result in slow or delayed charging. It's best to use the power supply that came with your Mac.

Comment: Don't do it. I unintentionally connected two Apple chargers into 2 MacBook Pro's and BOTH ended up failing. Apple might tell you it is supported but YOU will end up paying $795 each time you try it and it fails.

Comment: @RoriStumpf Kindly share this comment on the question instead of this answer so that the author of the question gets notified. Once done, please delete it from here.